# Verzeichnis von Wörtern die sowohl im Deutschen als auch in Sprache X existieren

Tags: written-language

Gibt es derartige Listen/Tabellen? Es geht dabei um Worte, die in exakt der gleichen Schreibweise in beiden Sprachen im Gebrauch sind und nicht unbedingt das gleiche bedeuten. Zum Beispiel:

Englisch:

- lies
- lose
- rot
- hell

Polnisch:

- ich
- jeden

Klar, dass es im Lateinischen Alphabet sein muss. Vielleicht gibt es dafür auch einen Fachbegriff, aber ich meine hier nicht unbedingt  *false friends*, sondern Worte, die zufällig die gleiche Schreibweise haben. Dabei ist die Groß- und Kleinschreibung egal.

Comment: Bezüglich false friends: Wenn die Bedeutung übereinstimmt, sind es genau false friends. Gift/gift ist da ein gutes Beispiel. Ergänzungsfrage: bezieht sich exakt gleiche Schreibweise auch auf Groß- und Kleinschreibung? Dann dürften viele Nomen nämlich schon rausfallen.

Comment: Guter Hinweis zu den _False Friends_, danke. Ich werde die Frage mal anpassen. Und Groß/Kleinschreibung ist egal.

Comment: Ich glaube was du suchst sind Homonyme. Genauere Unterscheidungen sind Homographen und Homophone. Im Englischen gibt es auch noch false cognates.

Comment: Ich sehe nicht, warum es solche Tabellen nicht geben soll, bezweifle aber, dass der Nutzen so hoch ist, dass sich jemand die Mühe macht. (In der Frage find ich auch keinen Anhaltspunkt für einen solchen Nutzen.) Im Bedarfsfall sollten solche Tabellen mit Hilfe der Wörterbuchdateien eines Spelling Checkers (etwa hunspell) maschinell erstellbar sein.

Comment: Wiktionary ist ja keinesfalls vollständig, hat aber eine sehr große Datenbasis womit du selbst solche Listen erstellen könntest. Schlägst du "lies" nach, siehst du z.B. dass es dafür Einträge für folgende Sprachen gibt: Englisch, Afrikaans, Niederländisch, Französisch, Deutsch, Latein, Limburgisch, Livisch, Luxemburgisch, Serbokroatisch und Schwedisch gibt: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lies

Answer (score 1):

Gleiche oder ähnliche Wörter mit gleicher Bedeutung in Englisch, Esperanto, Französisch, Italienisch und Schwedisch:
[https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Verzeichnis:Ähnliche_Wörter_mit_gleicher_Bedeutung_in_verschiedenen_Sprachen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Verzeichnis:%C3%84hnliche_W%C3%B6rter_mit_gleicher_Bedeutung_in_verschiedenen_Sprachen)

False Friends in rund 10 Sprachen:
https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Verzeichnis:Falsche_Freunde

Answer (score 1):

Es gibt m.W. keine Listen von Wörtern unterschiedlicher Sprachen, die zufälligerweise dieselbe Schreibung aufweisen, da diese Zufälle sprachwissenschaftlich nicht relevant sind. Du kannst dir eine solche Liste aber leicht selbst erstellen, indem du Listen von Wörtern unterschiedlicher Sprachen auf identische Zeichenketten *(strings)* durchsuchst. Das lässt sich leicht automatisieren, wenn man grundlegende Programmierkenntnisse besitzt.

Unterschiedlich vollständige Wortlisten gibt es frei im Internet. [Google ist dein Freund.](https://www.google.com/search?q=wortliste%20deutsch)